# how do I make this head fit on the bone without deforming

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, origin

so I need the head on the right to be placed on spine.006 but when I try to place it the head goes all wonky im trying to use the custom object thing under veiwport display.

bone before head is selected as custum object
[image]

head after
[image: b]

Comment: Suggestion.  Delete all armature modifiers from your [head objects] to give you a fresh start with your previous attempts [deleted].  Create a small head with rotation, scale, location [applied].  The head will likely need to be only as large as a single bone .. or use the armature modifier with the mode of [single bone].  The skull bone may need, in beginner actions, to be affected to be affected by only one bone.  You can try other options later.  You can search some of the concepts mentioned here at BSE.  Be ready to delete previous armature modifiers that fail .. and reapply new modifers.

Comment: I see your images and some effort to convey the problem.  The question is still only 50% clear to me.    One image shows 2 sphere and the next shows 3 spheres.  You may also help yourself by showing all modifiers and constraints on the sphere which has a behaviour that you does not meet your expectations.  Again ... since a sphere is quick to create .. I would delete some previous work and try fresh work and new application of an armature modifier.  When using Blender for the first few times (< 38) it is difficult to see common  mistakes.

Comment: The video website that has a name that rhymes with noonoob has many tutorials on using an armature ..  consider searching blender armature modifier tutorial.

Comment: so the sphere on the left is just a uv sphere I added to see if it would have the same effect. it didn't. the sphere on the right is a sculpted face that I made and the third sphere  one the 2nd image is what the bone looks like when I make the custum shape the face